# Rerouting When Using Own Computer As Server

Tags: node.js, url, routes, ip

I am currently making a website. I'd want people to try it out. They can do so right now if I send them my IP and port and they put it in the URL. My computer acts as the server right now.

Is there a way to use my computer as the server but without actually sharing directly my IP? Some kind of rerouting. I am not looking for something very secure, I am only looking for a solution that doesn't involve putting my IP in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a domain name (or use a free equivalent like FreeDNS), but your IP will still be visible to anyone who pings you server. You could rent a VPS and use that to proxy requests to your server, or you could use an anonymizing service like Tor to keep your IP hidden, but there's really no reason to go through all that trouble. If you're worried about people having your IP address, there's no reason to, because there's not really much people can do with it. If you're looking for an easier way for you to share it and for people to remember it, I suggest [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org) or [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/).

Comment: From the question, it doesn't look the OP was concerned about people knowing his IP - he just didn't want them to have to type it in to the url.

Comment: In that case, there's tons of free domain name sites out there in addition to the ones I mentioned.

Comment: Right now, my website is accessible via port 3000. (Url is xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000) If I'm using FreeDNS, how do I specify that it's the port 3000 that needs to be used? Or do I need to change it to port 80?

Comment: You'd just access it with `yourfreednsdomain.com:3000`. If you want people to access it on port 80, you'd have to change it to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using ngrok - https://ngrok.com/.

It allows you to run general internet traffic to any port on your local machine, via `somesubdomain.nkgrok.com`.  Also, it works if you're behind a firewall - you just open up a connection to ngrok from your computer, and ngrok will forward incoming traffic to your computer through that connection.